# Bootstrap scrollspy won't work

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

I'm trying to implement Bootstrap Scrollspy on a website I'm working on but no matter what I do, I can't seem to get it to work (or do *anything* for that matter).

The website can be viewed at http://thecreativecompany.stage.webcomm.com.au/

Here's my JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var offset_height = $("nav").height();

    $('#nav-wrapper').height(offset_height);

    $("nav").affix({
        offset: $("nav").position()
    });

    $('body').scrollspy({
        target: '#nav-menu',
        offset: offset_height
    });

    $('#menu li a').click(function (event) {
        var scrollPos = $('body').find($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - (offset_height - 1);

        $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: scrollPos
        }, 500);

        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're missing the `.nav` class in your menu. From the docs:

> Then add the data-target attribute with the ID or class of the parent
>   element of any Bootstrap **.nav** component.

So just add the class to your menu `<ul>`:

```
<div id="nav-menu">
    <ul id="menu" class="nav">
        <li><a href="#header">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Also, the result you'll get from the scrollspy plugin is an `.active` class being added to your list items, so I'm assuming you'll want to add a rule like this one to your CSS to go with your current styles:

```
#menu li.active:after {
    height: 6px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working now; I knew it had to be something small I was missing. I'm getting a strange issue where the About section is not triggering the #about nav item at the correct spot (only triggers a few hundred pixels down the About section). It seems to be working perfectly for the Work section so I'm not sure why it's not working correctly for the About section. Any ideas?

Comment: @Jordan Try initializing scrollspy inside `$('window').load(` instead of `$(document).ready(` to let all the page content load before the offsets are calculated